# testing for a package version set using custom cmake version variable

Tags: cmake, fltk

I'm linking to FLTK in my project using CMake and want to make sure that if anyone else tries to do so on their machine that they have the latest version (1.3.7).

The normal way in CMake to do this is

`find_package(FLTK 1.3.7 REQUIRED)`

However this requires variables like `PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR` etc. to be set in the relevant `FLTKConfig.cmake` file. Unfortunately, these are not set in this package, but what has been set is `set (FLTK_VERSION 1.3.7)`

How can I test that this variable (it might be set to 1.3.6 or 1.4.0 or whatever) is greater or equal to 1.3.7 in my `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` command [supports `VERSION` keyword](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#version-equal) to perform version numbers comparison:

```
if(${FLTK_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 1.3.7)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The use of `VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL` in your answer gave me the behaviour I needed.